# Don't validate hidden fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am new to javascript and all these html and stuff. I have the following code from w3schools that validates the input fields. I have html input fields that are like this.

```html
<div id="employed" style="display:none;">
    <p><input placeholder="Name Of The Organization / Institution ..."  name="organization"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Designation ..."  name="desig"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Place Of Work  ..."  name="workplace"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Communication Address ..."  name="cadd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="E_mail ID ..."  name="offemail"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Contact Number ..."  name="contact"></p>
  </div>
```

I have a javascript that shows the hidden field when user selects radio buttons.
But when I click next it validates the fields even if they are hidden.
The javascript for validation is this.

```js
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      //valid = false;
      (y[i].style.display == "none")?valid = true:valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Please I am learning right now and I am stuck here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the input dom is still avaiable in your document and it's just hidden only. To prevent your validation validates the hidden input. change your code to this.

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "" && y[i].parentElement.style.display != 'none') {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      //valid = false;
      (y[i].style.display == "none")?valid = true:valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: But it still validates the input. I think its because of the inline css like style.display=none I don't know.

Comment: your hidden input is the div and not the input itself right ?

Comment: Thanks Man. Its working now. It may be silly to say. But I had the <p> tag as its parent element not the <div> tag. When I removed it, its working now. Thanks a lot.